# How to remove or disable patosai tree multiselect

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, multi-select

as the title say
I have a problem with removing or disable select option tree multiselect patosai. Actually the disable or remove is working but the display not re-render.
any idea? here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htumxL5r/)

```
<input id="checkedTree" type="text"/>
<select id="test-select">
  <option value="1" data-section="fruit">Banana</option>
  <option value="2" data-section="fruit">Apple</option>
  <option value="3" data-section="fruit">Avocado</option>
  <option value="4" data-section="fruit">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="5" data-section="fruit">PenPineappleApplePen</option>
  <option value="6" data-section="animal">Tiger</option>
  <option value="7" data-section="animal">Lion</option>
  <option value="8" data-section="animal">Pitbull</option>
  <option value="9" data-section="animal">OrangUtan</option>
  <option value="10" data-section="animal">Marsupilami Yellow cartoon</option>
</select>

<button id="dis" onclick = "disableSelect()">
Remove apple and avocado
</button>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var $select = $('#test-select');
    $select.treeMultiselect({ 
    enableSelectAll: true,
    sortable: false, 
    searchable: true,
    startCollapse: true,
    onChange:function(){
        if ($select.val() != null){
            document.getElementById("checkedTree").value = $select.val();
        }else{
            document.getElementById("checkedTree").value = "";
        }   
    }

    });

});


  function disableSelect(){
  document.getElementById("test-select").remove(2);
  document.getElementById("test-select").remove(2); 
    //document.getElementById("checkedTree").value = "success";
  }
```

the proof its working, the value that i get when checked those apple and avocado is null...

Btw, is there any way to make 2 select using patosai tree multiselect on same page? How?

Answer (score 1):

That library actually changes the HTML structure of your select box. You have provided this

```
<select id="test-select">
  <option value="1" data-section="fruit">Banana</option>
  <option value="2" data-section="fruit">Apple</option>
  <option value="3" data-section="fruit">Avocado</option>
  <option value="4" data-section="fruit">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="5" data-section="fruit">PenPineappleApplePen</option>
  <option value="6" data-section="animal">Tiger</option>
  <option value="7" data-section="animal">Lion</option>
  <option value="8" data-section="animal">Pitbull</option>
  <option value="9" data-section="animal">OrangUtan</option>
  <option value="10" data-section="animal">Marsupilami Yellow cartoon</option>
</select>
```

But when using patosai's plugin, it becomes as here below

```
<div class="section" data-key="0">
  <div class="title"><span class="collapse-section">-</span>
    <input class="section" type="checkbox">fruit</div>
  <div class="item" data-key="0" data-value="1">
    <input class="option" type="checkbox" id="treemultiselect-0-0">
    <label for="treemultiselect-0-0">Banana</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="3" data-value="4">
    <input class="option" type="checkbox" id="treemultiselect-0-3">
    <label for="treemultiselect-0-3">Pineapple</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="4" data-value="5">
    <input class="option" type="checkbox" id="treemultiselect-0-4">
    <label for="treemultiselect-0-4">PenPineappleApplePen</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section" data-key="1">
  <div class="title"><span class="collapse-section">-</span>
    <input class="section" type="checkbox">animal</div>
  <div class="item" data-key="5" data-value="6">
    <input class="option" type="checkbox" id="treemultiselect-0-5">
    <label for="treemultiselect-0-5">Tiger</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="6" data-value="7">
    <input class="option" type="checkbox" id="treemultiselect-0-6">
    <label for="treemultiselect-0-6">Lion</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="7" data-value="8">
    <input class="option" type="checkbox" id="treemultiselect-0-7">
    <label for="treemultiselect-0-7">Pitbull</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="8" data-value="9">
    <input class="option" type="checkbox" id="treemultiselect-0-8">
    <label for="treemultiselect-0-8">OrangUtan</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-key="9" data-value="10">
    <input class="option" type="checkbox" id="treemultiselect-0-9">
    <label for="treemultiselect-0-9">Marsupilami Yellow cartoon</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which means that you have to select your elements differently. I have inspected the document and what you need is the following;

```
function disableSelect() {
  $('.item[data-value="2"]').remove(); // removes apple
  $('.item[data-value="3"]').remove(); // removes avocado
}
```

To remove those two elements. Here is an updated fiddle to check it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/htumxL5r/1/

Comment: Thank you @KarelG  your code work, but if i select all i still get the all value (1-10) its should be (1,3-10). Is there any way to re-render?